# Remove single quotes in one of the table column in SQl server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, date

I am trying to implement query to remove the single quotations existing in few rows in the entire column.

I have tried the following queries to try to implement it, but no luck. Please do help me.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(saleDate,1) = '"' AND LEFT(saleDate,1) = '"' THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF(saleDate, 1, 1, '')), 1, 1, '')) 
       WHEN RIGHT(saleDate,1) = '"' THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(saleDate), 1, 1, '')) 
       WHEN LEFT(saleDate,1) = '"' THEN STUFF(saleDate, 1, 1, '')
       ELSE saleDate END as saleDate
FROM [Staging].[Target_ActivationFlowPrepaidAct];
```

---

```
SET saleDate = REPLACE(saleDate,'"', '')
```

---

```
SELECT TRIM(leading '' FROM saleDate) FROM [Staging].[Target_ActivationFlowPrepaidAct]
```

Data -

```
saleDate
2020/04/20 12:42:05
2020/04/22 11:35:58
2020/04/24 08:10:50
2020/04/25 10:06:59
'2018-11-29 12:47:23'
'2018-12-04 18:36:08'
'2018-12-10 11:33:09'
'2018-12-15 12:33:08'
```

output -

```
saleDate
2020/04/20 12:42:05
2020/04/22 11:35:58
2020/04/24 08:10:50
2020/04/25 10:06:59
2018-11-29 12:47:23
2018-12-04 18:36:08
2018-12-10 11:33:09
2018-12-15 12:33:08
```

Comment: Why do your "dates" have a single quote (`'`) character in the first place? That means that aren't a date and time datatype, they're `varchar`s. Also, `"` isn't a single quote, it's a double quote, so `REPLACE(saleDate,'"', '')` is never going to replace any single quotes as `"` and `'` are different characters. It's like using the expression `REPLACE('apples','t','')` and expecting the result `apple`.

Comment: @Larnu - They have single quotes because few source data files, have single quotes and few others doesn't, so while i ran the ETL, the output came out in that way. Its fine to see the output from target table in that way, but while executing views, there is an error throwing while casting, so i need to remove the quotations entirely in the target table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're just looking for **[`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)**

```
CREATE View MyData AS
SELECT
'2020/04/20 12:42:05' Value
UNION ALL SELECT '2020/04/22 11:35:58'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020/04/24 08:10:50'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020/04/25 10:06:59'
UNION ALL SELECT '2018-11-29 12:47:23'
UNION ALL SELECT '''2018-12-04 18:36:08'''
UNION ALL SELECT '''2018-12-10 11:33:09'''
UNION ALL SELECT '''2018-12-15 12:33:08''';

SELECT Value, REPLACE(Value, '''', '') OutputValue
FROM MyData;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f013fc1ec5d358ad0af4e6f2e46f07d0)

Comment: can i just replace instead of select the single quotations ' ' with nothing for the entire saledate column by modifying the entire target table , because I am trying to execute a view which is trying to cast
select cast([saleDate] as Date) as saledate, which is where is throwing the error, hence i want to replace the single quotations with nothing.

Comment: And that what my answer do, you can add also `CAST(REPLACE(Value, '''', '') AS DATETIME)` or `CAST(REPLACE(Value, '''', '') AS DATE)` as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store dates as strings. Instead, you should be using a `date`-like datatype... and wouldn't need to ask this question.

That said, if you want to remove leading and trailing single quotes, you can use `TRIM()`:

```
SELECT TRIM('''' from saledate) orderdate
FROM [Staging].[Target_ActivationFlowPrepaidAct];
```

Note that the single quote needs to be escaped with an additional single quote.

The upside of this approach is that it only removes single quotes at the beginning and end of the string, not possible embedded strings. While this does not seem to make a difference for your use case, this might be important in more complex situations.